# Magento filtering showing wrong count

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, filter

For filtering purpose I have Manadev extension for this filter count showing wrongly.

For example I have category called "shirt". In this category having only two products, but price filtering showing like this.

> 0-100(1)
>   101-200(1)
>   200-300(1)
>   300-400(1)

Like this it's showing. When I click on first two it's showing products. 3rd and 4th showing empty.
I don't know what is happening.

Comment: try rebuilding the manadev indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you mean i want install this extension again.

Comment: no. Check the system->index management section and see if there is something in there related to manadev.

Comment: Yes, 3 index available 1.Default Values (MANAdev) 2.SEO Schemas (MANAdev) 3. SEO URL Rewrites (MANAdev).  already reindexed. all of them in green.

Comment: any one pls help me

Comment: HI mohan did you got any answers please share..